# Import "flask_login" could not be resolved

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I was following this tutorial on creating a website with Flask using Python and one of the steps had me import flask_login. However, whenever I do an error on vs code pops up saying Import "flask_login" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports).

The same thing happened earlier in the tutorial when I tried importing Flask, but then I changed my interpreter and it somehow resolved itself. I've been attempting changing interpreters again and it did not work. I have also confirmed that flask-login was indeed installed. I also saw something about needing an environment active so I activated a virtual environment. It just made all of the imports have the same error sign that I had earlier with only flask_login.

Comment: Show us the actual code and the actual error message.